# Align duplicates on the same row between two columns in two sheets & listing other columns sorted

Tags: excel

I have Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet1 is the master.

In sheet2 I have columns ABC with rows 1-10. I would like to align the duplicates of the Sheet2 ColumnA to Sheet1 ColumnA and keep/list the additional information from other columns in sorted fashion in Sheet1.

I found the following formula that would help me list the duplicates but I am not sure how to incorporate the rest of the information from Sheet2.

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)),"No match",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A2,A:A,0)))
```

For example:

Sheet1

```
A  B  C
1  z  x
2  z  x
3  z  x
4  z  x
5  z  x
6  z  x
7  z  x
8  z  x
9  z  x
10 z  x
```

Sheet2

```
A   B   C   D
10  a   !   5/19/07
5   b   ^   5/19/07
3   c   %   6/18/13
7   d   $   8/3/22
8   e   #   6/18/13
1   f   @   8/3/22
2   g   ^   6/18/13
4   h   &   5/3/04
9   i   *   6/3/10
6   j   (   3/14/16
```

I need to have:

Sheet1

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   z   x   1   a   !   5/19/07
2   z   x   2   b   ^   5/19/07
3   z   x   3   c   %   6/18/13
4   z   x   4   d   $   8/3/22
5   z   x   5   e   #   6/18/13
6   z   x   6   f   @   8/3/22
7   z   x   7   g   ^   6/18/13
8   z   x   8   h   &   5/3/04
9   z   x   9   i   *   6/3/10
10  z   x   10  j   (   3/14/16
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there would be better way of doing this compared to what I would do, but here is my solution.

1. Concatenate columns A, B, C & D in Column E of Sheet2 using a
   special character like a pipe. Then drag down to last row to copy formula.

   ```
   =CONCATENATE(A1,"|",B1,"|",C1,"|",D1)
   ```
2. Then on Sheet1, use Index & Match or you can use your
   formula but indexed column would be "E" of sheet2.

   =IF(ISNA(INDEX(Sheet2!$E$1:$E$10,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10,0))),"No Match",INDEX(Sheet2!$E$1:$E$10,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10,0)))
3. Select the column on sheet1 where you've applied Index, Match
   formula and paste special as values. This will paste actual values.
4. Now by doing this we have all information for each column on sheet1.

   select column D

   select Data->Text-to-columns and in the dialog window select other
   delimited formatting then type '|'.

   click next then choose correct format for each data type.

   click Finish

   This will delimit all information into respective columns.

PS: I'm assuming that your columns doesn't have header. If there is header then use range A2:A10 or E2:E10 or whatever.

Hope this will help...

Comment: The problem is that I will need to do further manipulation of information from those columns from Sheet2 that I need in need Sheet1, so I need them transferred as their own columns.

Comment: I think what you're saying is achieved in step 4 above. When you do text to column (for example column D of sheet1 where your data looks like to be "A|B|C|D" after concatenation & match formula) the cell contents will spread over 4 different columns (D, E, F & G). I've added more points to step 4. see if this makes sense.